# How to retain a value in variable for consecutive execution of the pl script

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am new to perl scripting. Need your suggestion for the same

I have a *xyz.pl* script which runs to success or failure. If it fails, I need to save the checkpoint where it failed e.g. the failure name in a variable

```
$var=job[0];
```

When I rerun *xyz.pl* for the second time, it should read this variable **$var** and picks its value and start from job where it failed and not from the beginning.

In perl, is it possible? Is there variable which can retain the value for the above scenario for consecutive runs of the script.

Please advise.

Comment: You can't magiacally leak a variable into another process that hasn't even started yet. But you could write your values to a configuration file and initilaize with those values on start-up, or pass your values as command line parameters

Comment: thanks amon...is there any other way other than the use of files etc...??

Comment: No, files are the only persistent object on a computer. But you could always change your architecture so that you don't exit your script on failure but simply retry.

Comment: Why is the use of a file an unsatisfactory solution for you? Very often a log file is sufficient to resume a broken sequence

Comment: @borodin ill hve to learn file manipulation and then try it out...Thanks!!

Comment: Please check the answer for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902812/how-can-i-serialize-and-deserialize-perl-data-to-from-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable cannot survive the end of a script. However, you can save the value into a file from which you can later read it back into another run of the script.

Comment: so what is this use state variable in perl??

Comment: is there any oother way other the use of file manipulation?..if so can you pls suggest....

Comment: A state variable is used in a subroutine to keep its value in successive calls of the subroutine.